# Android - Communicating between fragments, adapter is null

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, notifydatasetchanged

I've been looking for an answer for a while now, but I haven't been able to find the same situation, so I'll try asking it here.

I'm currently creating an app with an Activity, 2 fragments and viewpager functionality. Fragment 1 has a button that will update the list on fragment 2 (the usual way, frag 1 -> activity -> frag 2) and when it reaches that method and calls notifyDataSetChanged it crashes because the adapter is null. Apparently the adapter is null and the existing List to fill the listview is empty (which isn't a huge problem because it gets filled again, but I'd like to keep the original items).

How can I update my list and why is my adapter null?

My code:

MainActivity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements FirstFragment.OnUpdatedListListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TestAdapter mAdapter;

    //Lifecycle functions
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.TestPager);
        mAdapter = new TestAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onListUpdated() {
        logcat("Click received in main");
        SecondFragment sf = SecondFragment.newInstance();

        if (sf == null || !sf.isInLayout()) {
            logcat("frag == null || !frag.isInLayout()");

            SecondFragment newFragment = SecondFragment.newInstance();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            newFragment.setArguments(args);

            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.second_fragment, newFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            newFragment.receiver();
        } else {
            logcat("frag bestaat");

            sf.receiver();
        }
    }
}
```

ListItemAdapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ListItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListItem> {

    private final Context context;
    private List<ListItem> items;

    public ListItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ListItem> values) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_items, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = values;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView tvName;
        TextView tvDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = convertView;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_items, parent, false);

            ViewHolder viewholder = new ViewHolder();
            viewholder.tvName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            viewholder.tvDescription = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);
            rowView.setTag(viewholder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();

        holder.tvName.setText(items.get(position).getName());
        holder.tvDescription.setText(items.get(position).getDescription());

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

SecondFragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {
    private final static String TAG = "SecondFragment";

    private List<ListItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView lv;
    private ListItemAdapter adapter;

    public SecondFragment() {}
    public static SecondFragment newInstance() {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        secondFragment.setArguments(args);

        return secondFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        items.add(new ListItem(1, "Willem", "Willemkeurige beschrijving"));
        items.add(new ListItem(2, "Jos", "De Klos"));
        items.add(new ListItem(3, "Leo", "Pold"));

        adapter = new ListItemAdapter(getActivity(), 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

        lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvSecond);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

    public void receiver() {
        items.add(new ListItem(4, "Willem2", "Willemkeurige beschrijving"));
        items.add(new ListItem(5, "Jos2", "De Klos"));
        items.add(new ListItem(6, "Leo", "Pold3"));

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

In `MyActivity` add:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    //...
    private ListItemAdapter mAdapter;
    public ListItemAdapter getAdapter(){
        if (mAdapter==null){
            mAdapter = new ListItemAdapter();
        }
        return mAdapter;
    }
}
```

In your `Fragment` you can get the `Adapter` using:

```
((MyActivity)getActivity()).getAdapter();
```

This way you can "share" your `Adapter`.

Comment: Isn't there a better way where I don't have to touch the MainActivity? I'm going to expand the app later and add several fragments with similar functionality. This would mean I would have to create an adapter in my MainActivity for each one of them while there must be a way to avoid doing this and have cleaner code.

Comment: You could create a `MyActivity` which extends `FragmentActivity` and the `getAdapter` method is the only addition. Then all your future Activities will extend `MyActivity`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your calling receiver() before the fragment has been added. The fragment has its own lifecycle, so there is not guarantee that onCreate and onCreateView has been called. This is why your adapter is null. To fix this you can do:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);

    lv = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lvSecond);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    receiver();
    return v;
}

public void receiver(){
    //add your strings as normal
    if(adapter != null){
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this works, but it immediately executes receive() and ignores the button, so refreshing the list when I want to still isn't possible. When I try to use the button it still crashes.

Comment: Already implemented that to avoid crashing, but it will not update my list.

Comment: What are you updating it with? Right now it looks like you are replacing with exactly the same data

Comment: In my receive() method I'm adding 3 items to the list.